# How to use server_name with stream NGINX?

Tags: nginx, video-streaming

Current setup as follows:

```
stream  {
    server {
        server_name stream.kingdomgame.org; # this line is resulting in an error
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1935;
    }
}
```

Works just fine without server_name, but I'd like to use a domain if possible.

Comment: you can use alibaba tengine instead of nginx.

Answer (score 6):

`server_name` is used to specify HTTP virtual host name for a `server` block.

`stream` module is a TCP stream proxy module, and TCP streams have no concepts of virtual host names.

So, the answer is that you cannot use `server_name` with `stream` module.